# Problems saving values in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults

I have this as my `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (defaults == [cells objectAtIndex:0])
    {
        NSString * myFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"cells" ofType:@"plist"];
        cells = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:myFile];
    }
    else
    {
        [defaults stringForKey:@"string1"];
    }
}
```

And for my `viewWillDisappear` I have:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    string1 = [cells objectAtIndex:0];
    [defaults setObject:string1 forKey:@"string1"];
}
```

But I cannot get the data to be saved. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you setting defaults to `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` somewhere?  Also, why are you comparing it to the first object in the cells array?  Seems strange.

You've otherwise got the idea correct.  Make sure the viewWillDisappear method is actually getting called.  Also you can call `[NSUserDefaults synchronize]` to save the changes immediately.

One last thing, you aren't doing anything in that else {} block.  You need to assign the value of `[defaults stringForKey:@"string1"];` to a variable to use it.

Comment: no im not setting it to that. and i was using that to compare if the defaults ivar was empty. and in the else block i did set defaults to that?

Comment: it will throw an exception if the NSArray `cells` exists and is empty.  you want to test if it's nil, and load it if so `if (cells == nil) { /* load cells */ }`

Answer (score 3):

`defaults` should be an instance of `NSUserDefaults`:

```
defaults = [NSUserDefaults sharedUserDefaults];
```

Therefore, `if (defaults == [cells objectAtIndex:0])` is not a valid line of code and it will never be equal unless you're fiddling with the RAM.

Otherwise, the code looks fine.

Comment: OH okay awesome!! thanks a lot! and for the if statement how should i test to see if its empty? Thanks man :D

Comment: Well, you want to read the value from defaults into string1 first, then check to see if `string1 == nil`